# Implementing onData in 'dart:html' dispatchEvent

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am developing an application but I noticed that each class has a lot of similar code to the one below addRace method in the class below:

```dart
@CustomTag( 'race-view' )
class RaceViewForm extends PolymerElement
{
  RaceViewForm.created() : super.created();

  void addRace( Event e, var detail, Element target )
  {
     var raceElem = $['race'];

    if( raceElem.children.length < 1 )
    {
      raceElem.children.add( new Element.tag( 'race-form' ) );
    }

    raceElem.on[ DELETE_BUTTON_FORM_EVENT ]
            .listen( (Event e)
                {
                   (e.target as Element).remove();
                   dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( RACE_VIEW_EVENT, detail:new Race() ));
                });

  }

}
```

I have attempted to move the repeating code into a library called shared.dart with the following refactoring:

```dart
  import 'dart:html';
  import 'package:observe/observe.dart';
  ...

  void addForm( Element target, String eventName, String dispatchEventName, dynamic instance )
  {
    var element = target;

    if( element.children.length < 1 )
    {
      element.children.add( new Element.tag( 'race-form' ) );
    }

    element.on[ eventName ]
            .listen( (Event e)
                {
                   (e.target as Element).remove();
                  dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( dispatchEventName, detail:instance ));
                });

  }
```

However, the dart IDE flags the dispatchEvent method in the addForm method as being not defined with parameter onData (dynamic) -> void. Given that dispatchEvent is in the 'dart:html' package, I am uncertain as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a `dispatchEvent()` in `dart:html` (top level) only as method of the `Node` class. You need to pass your Polymer element instance to the library method.

You could implement it as a mixin to make it easier to reuse.
See https://github.com/donny-dont/Pixelate/blob/master/lib/components/expander/expander.dart#L41 (`Expandable`, `Customizeable`) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I will take a look at the implementation.